# Passing the form between classes and acces functions in the passed form

Tags: c#, forms, class, object

I am accesing another file by doing this:

```
 public void startUpdateChecking()
    {
        UpdateHandler process = new UpdateHandler();
        process.initialize(this);
    }
```

The same class that 'startUpdateChecking' function is in I have this example functon aswell:

```
 public void changeText(string Text)
        {
          label2.Text = Text;
        }
```

Now in the UpdateHandler class I am doing this:

```
 public Form form;
        public void initialize(Form test)
        {
            Thread update = new Thread(checkForUpdates);
            update.Start();
            form = test;
            edit();
        }

        public void edit() {
        form.changeText("test");
        }
```

But 'form' has no clue what changeText is for some reason, how would I make it so I can use functions from another class (Form2 class) WITHOUT the need for static function?

I tried doing:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
```

And I could control and acces things from Form2, but this makes a new form instead of controlling the current one that is active (aka nothing visible happends using this).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `form` is a base class, it needs to be the specific class

Comment: Without going on a rant about design...., you need to pass a reference to the update handler. e.g. `new UpdateHandler(form2)` or use a static instance of Form2.

Comment: @James Barrass care to show a example of the first option? Also please do rant about design, I can only learn from it.

Comment: Also if I change the function to static, then basicly I need to start converting nealy everything I do and in the future to static.. because this is just a example but in the real program the function I am trying to acces is a big part of the program which also has a lot of sub functions.

Comment: The design side of it should avoid tying classes together like this, it prevents code re-use and makes things like unit testing much more work than they need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a delegate to pass the changeText method instead of passing the whole form. This should help separate the classes and I think would improve the design.

A quick way of doing this would use an action. Instead of passing in `Form` to `initialize` pass `Action<Text>`

The form side code would change to

```
 public void startUpdateChecking()
    {
        UpdateHandler process = new UpdateHandler();
        process.initialize((s) => {changeText(s);});
    }
```

and the UpdateHandler side code would change to

```
    public void initialize(Action<string> outputMethod)
    {
        Thread update = new Thread(checkForUpdates);
        update.Start();
        output= outputMethod;
        edit();
    }

    public void edit() {
    output("test");
    }
```

Comment: I need to acces a function in Form2 form, aka the class that 'startUpdateChecking' is. Or I am just not getting your code?

Comment: @user2911924 you are, but through the `Action` indirectly. UpdateHandler calls `outputMethod`, `outputMethod` calls `changeText`

Answer (score 0):

Try to return a value from initialize and then pass that on to ChangeText.

like this:

```
public void startUpdateChecking()
{
    UpdateHandler process = new UpdateHandler();
    string Value1 = process.initialize(this);
    ChangeText(Value1);
}
```

Initialize should then be a string, im not sure what the form is doing there, and what it has to do with the Thread update, thats something you probably know more about

```
    public string initialize(string test)
    {
        Thread update = new Thread(checkForUpdates);
        update.Start();
        form = test;
        return test;
    }
```

Just don't try to call a function from out a class, best way is to return from a class and then call a function